# Invoke class from parameter

Tags: ruby

I have the following method:

```
def parse_data(key:, type:)
  elements = self.xml_doc.css(key)
  return nil if elements.empty?
  element = elements.first
  return nil if element['resultType'] == NOT_AVAILABLE
  type(element.content)
end
```

The method is called like so:

```
def cash_collection
  parse_data(key: "item[@alias='COLLECTIONDAYS']", type: Float)
end
```

The problem is that in Ruby you have the class `Float` and you have the method called `Float()`. What I am trying to achieve is that the last line of my `parse_data` method mimics the following behaviour, but in a smart way so that I do not have to type it for every class:

```
Float(element.content) if type.is_a?(Float)
Integer(element.content) if type.is_a?(Integer)
```

Is there a way that when I pass the class `Float` as `type:` parameter, that the code knows it needs to invoke `Float()` without having to explicit write it? I'm thinking about some reflection methods or something.

**UPDATE:**
Currently I've worked around this by using the `.send` method on my data and simply pass the correct method as parameter, but if there's no way around this, I will keep this approach.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: seriously? How do I get my `type` parameter invoked as `type(element.content)` when I pass in `Float` as type. Cause right now Ruby think type points to a function.

Comment: Are you aware that `Float` as a constant (class) and the `Float` in `Float(...)` are different things?

Comment: Ruby does not think anything. If something happens, then that is the way it works.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to implement, that I can pass that parameter and create a new float for example, or `Integer`, or `Double`.

Comment: you could use `Kernel.send('Float','3.5')` but note this will only work for `Array`,`Complex`,`Float`,`Hash`,`Integer`,`Rational`,and `String`. but this still involves send which for some reason you are philosophically opposed to even though it is one of the best ways to accomplish your desired result. The constant `Float` does not have an initializer like `new` it relies on `Kernel#Float`

Comment: i know it works, currently using this as I know no other way around it. Which is why I posted the question. Sticking to the `.send` at the moment. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You talk about functions, but Ruby doesn't have functions. You talk about invoking classes, but you can't invoke classes, only methods and blocks. Can you clarify what it is that you want to achieve here?

Comment: rewritten the question, can't make it any more clearer then this.

Comment: So, you want to dynamically invoke a method whose name is the same as the name of a class? Then you can use `Module#name` for getting the name and `Object#send` for calling the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a constant [`Float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Float.html) (the class) and a global method [`Float()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Float):

```
defined? Float   #=> "constant"
defined? Float() #=> "method"
```

these are different things and you can't invoke the method on the constant:

```
type = Float
type() #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for main:Object
```

You could invoke the global method using a symbol:

```
Kernel.public_send(:Float, '1.2')
#=> 1.2
```

or via the class name:

```
Kernel.public_send(Float.name, '1.2')
#=> 1.2
```

Note that this will only work for classes / constants that have a global method with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Float` as a constant (class) and `Float` as a method (as in `Float(...)`) are different things, there is no built-in way to convert one from another. It is a conincidence that they are spelled the same.

Understanding that, you can probably go via strings. For example, using:

```
Float.name # => "Float"
```

the code may be:

```
def parse_data(key:, type:)
  ...
  send(type.name, ...)
end

def cash_collection
  parse_data(key: ..., type: Float)
end
```